# Menu xml file causing activity to immediately crash

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have been stuck on this for a few days now. Whenever I open ChannelActivity it errors once it reaches `setContentView(R.layout.channel_activity)`
Other threads I've seen were resolved by fixing an issue inside of the menu xml or by moving the menu xml into a menu resource type directory.

I still get the same errors even if my menu class has nothing inside of it, aside from `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` and i have doubly amde sure that my menu xml was correctly placed into a menu resource type directory.

Any help as to pointing out the cause of, or fixing the error would be greaty appreciated as I'm not sure what to do at this point.

FATAL EXCEPTION Error:

```
11-29 21:43:36.610 15965-15965/edu.illinois.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: edu.illinois.finalproject, PID: 15965
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.illinois.finalproject/edu.illinois.finalproject.ChannelActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class menu
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class menu
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class menu
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.menu" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/edu.illinois.finalproject-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:707)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:724)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:792)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:976)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                               at edu.illinois.finalproject.ChannelActivity.onCreate(ChannelActivity.java:45)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
11-29 21:43:36.610 15965-15965/edu.illinois.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Render Error:

```
The following classes could not be found:
 - menu
 - item
```

---

channel_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.illinois.finalproject.ChannelActivity">

    <include layout="@menu/channel_toolbar"
             android:id="@+id/channelToolbar"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

channel_menu.xml: (located in res/menu, with resource type set as menu)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/create_channel"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_create"
          android:title="@string/create"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

ChannelActivity:

```
public class ChannelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.channel_activity);   //<--------------- ERROR
  }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.channel_toolbar, menu);

    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `channel_activity` with `channel_layout` and `channel_toolbar` with `channel_menu`:

```
public class ChannelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.channel_layout);   
 }

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.channel_menu, menu);

  return true;
 }
}
```

and remove that line from `channel_layout.xml` file.

```
    <include layout="@menu/channel_toolbar"  
         android:id="@+id/channelToolbar"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I took your suggestions and renamed my files, and you were correct on the main issue as well.

Comment: Yep, names always create confusions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't include menu in layout. So remove the following:

```
<include layout="@menu/channel_toolbar"
             android:id="@+id/channelToolbar"/>
```

Comment: Ah, it was that simple... Thanks, though! You fixed my problem

Comment: You're welcome ;). I once experienced the same problem :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I hope you will be not getting this error.
    public class ChannelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.channel_layout);   //<--------------- ERROR
  }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.channel_menu, menu);

    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You inflate wrong menu xml file in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

change this:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.channel_toolbar, menu);
```

To:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.channel_menu, menu);
```

Happy coding!!